# Multiple Command line arguments in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, command-line-arguments, getopt

I am wondering the best way to process multiple command line arguments. I have seen command line arguments done with switch and case statements like this:

```
while ((x = getopt(argc, argv, "bic:")) != -1){
switch (x){
  case 'b':
    //do something
    break;
  case 'i':
    //do something
    break;
  case 'c':
    //do something
    break;  
  default:
    break;
}
```

This works fine. However, It doesn't lend itself very well to working with multiple command line arguments. For the project I'm working on if I enter multiple arguments I would want that to be a combination of the two cases, if that makes sense. So the division between cases is a bit annoying... I guess I could make separate cases for each combination, like `case: 'ib'` or `case: 'ibc'`
But is there a simpler solution?

Also, I am trying to find a solution where it doesn't matter the order of arguments entered. `a.out -b -c` should be the same as `a.out -c -b`

Comment: Well, you already have a loop, so your code already handles multiple arguments (the `break` just leaves the `switch`, not the loop). What exactly is the issue?

Comment: You could set variables `got_flag_b`, `got_flag_c` etc in your `switch` and only after you have looped over all the parameters, start your application logic operating depending on the values of that variables.  There is [a GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) to also process long options but I think that is about as far as you can go in C without using code generation.

Comment: Not that I'm used to getopt, but this code seems to process multiple arguments (hence the loop). For the "order does not matter" part, you should just set boolean flags in this loop, an afterwards just act according to the flags.

Comment: @NPE I guess I should clarify what my project does. Basically each case modifies a text file in a different way. Case 'b' removes any spaces before the first word on each line of text. Case 'i' removes all spaces on a line between the first and last word. Case 'c' removes all spaces after the last word on a line. I have each individual case working properly. However, I am still trying to figure out how to do multiple cases efficiently. For example if I did -b -i, I would want to remove the preceding spaces all other spaces before the last word.

Comment: It seems your problem is more about combining multiple text transformations into one than parsing command line arguments then.  But as said before, break that logic apart.  Have your text processing function take three boolean parameters for “a”, “b” and “c” and once you know that is working, figure out how to set those parameters depending on the command line options your program receives.

Comment: You could let go of `getopt()` if it doesn't do what you want, and process each `argv[]` in a loop based on `argc`. You will be able to handle the logic as you wish, for example, you can parse each term to see what switches are combined, then it won't matter what order of arguments, or of the commands within each (subject to dependency).

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand from your comments, I would expect the code to look something like this.  It is not clear why you have `c` taking an argument.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    int i_flag = 0;
    int b_flag = 0;
    int c_flag = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "bci")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'b':
            b_flag = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            c_flag = 1;
            break;
        case 'i':
            i_flag = 1;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-bci] [file ...]\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (optind < argc)
    {
        for (int i = optarg; i < argc; i++)
        {
            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (fp == 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[i]);
            else
            {
                process_file(fp, argv[i], b_flag, c_flag, i_flag);
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        process_file(stdin, "-", b_flag, c_flag, i_flag);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*Warning: uncompiled code.*</sup>

The `process_file()` function has a signature such as:

```
void process_file(FILE *fp, const char *fn, int b_flag, int c_flag, int i_flag);
```

If you want to rewrite the files, you have to decide whether you'll handle standard input (no file name) and if so, how.  If you simply write the new file to standard output, it is easy to handle standard input too.

You can revise the code so that you can detect whether `process_file()` succeeded (for example, it returns an integer instead of `void`) and modify the exit status of the program according to whether all files were processed successfully.  You can decide your functions don't need the file name (which avoids you having to specify a name such as `"-"` or `"/dev/stdin"` for standard input).

You can make the flags into global variables, and the `process_file()` function can apply the appropriate transformations to each line.  You can decide to do multiple transforms on each file, opening and closing the file between each transform, or rewinding the file between each transform, if you wish.  However, that is going to be slower than doing the three transforms in parallel.

The GNU version [`getopt()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) provides argument permutation so that you can execute:

```
program -b -c -i name-of-file
program name-of-file -b -c -i
program -b name-of-file -i -c
```

and they'll all work the same (and you still use the code above).  Personally, I dislike that, but I'm old fashioned.  You can turn it off if you're careful — one way is via the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable.  You can also arrange for `getopt()` to return the files as if they were arguments with the option code `'\1'` (<kbd>Control-A</kbd>).

Comment: This looks like a good solution. In fact, couldn't I go away with the switch statement all together? with something like this: while ((x = getopt(argc, argv, "bie:")) != -1){
  if (x == 'b')
   get_b = true;
  else if (x == 'i')
   get_i = true;
  else if (x == 'e')
   get_e = true;
  }

Comment: Yes, you can use a chained set of `if` and `else if` statements, but the switch is usually reckoned to be easier to understand.

Comment: Incidentally, I use a library function to wrap the last loop, so my program ends up as `filter(argc, argv, optind, processfile);` — which demands that the flags are globals.